# 2D Bullet spread on unity 2018.2

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm actually trying to do a 2D action game on unity 2018.
I want to do a bullet spread when I shoot with a gun, i need to specify that the gun shoot on the mouse cursor. I've searched all around the web, and hardly found a solution. So the code I've wrote with a tutorial not work as I want it to, 
either the bullets leave spread and towards the cursor, but are rotated in the wrong axis, and bug.

```
void Shoot()
{
    Vector3 fireDirection = spawnPoint.right;

    Quaternion fireRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(fireDirection);

    Quaternion randomRotation = Random.rotation;

    fireRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(fireRotation, randomRotation, Random.Range(0.0f, maxBulletSpreadAngle));

    nextFire = Time.time + 1f / fireRate;
    Instantiate(Balle, spawnPoint.position, fireRotation);
    ballesRestantes--;
}
```

or leave spread, rotated on the good axis, but don't follow the cursor, just shoot straight ahead.

```
 void Shoot()
{
    Vector3 fireDirection = spawnPoint.forward;

    Quaternion fireRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(fireDirection);

    Quaternion randomRotation = Random.rotation;

    fireRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(fireRotation, randomRotation, Random.Range(0.0f, maxBulletSpreadAngle));

    nextFire = Time.time + 1f / fireRate;
    Instantiate(Balle, spawnPoint.position, fireRotation);
    ballesRestantes--;
}
```

I hope someone can help me, and sorry for bad English, I'm french.

Comment: Where is the code for them to follow the cursor?

Comment: Sorry I've bad explain myself, the bullets don't follow the cursor, the weapon shoot were my cursor is.

Comment: I don't see the code for that either...  it looks like your bullets are either firing forward or to the right, there is nothing in what you provided that indicates you are shooting at the mouses position.

Comment: Something like `Vector3 fireDirection = (Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - spawnPoint.position).normalized;`...

Comment: You posted two chunks of code and they're identical.

Comment: @Draco18s the only difference is the `fireDirection` line

Comment: yep, its a very little difference, 
@Eddge 
the code is : 
`void Update()
    {
        Vector3 difference = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
        difference.Normalize();
        float rotZ = Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotZ);

    }
`

Comment: and its on a different script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is instead of shooting the bullets where your curser is, you put an offset value and by the help of Random.Range(-offset, offset) you can get random values close to your curser's position and make the bullets go to those positions.

Comment: I dont know exactly how to do that but i'll try. (i'm a total beginner in unity)

Comment: Glad it helped. Can you mark my answer as correct answer please :) @AlexSoti